# table width in multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn, width

I have some table

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xrr}
A  & B  & C  \\
\multicolumn{3}{p{XXX}}{Test}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

where the second row should span the entire table width. I wonder what needs to replace `XXX` in `p{XXX}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` you declare a table that is as wide as the textwidth. For the width of the `multicolumn` you can load the `calc` package and use `\textwidth-2\tabcolsep` (`2\tabcolsep` to account for the small horizontal white space to the left and right of each cell):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xrr}
A  & B  & C  \\
\multicolumn{3}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{some long text in this column some long text in this column some long text in this column some long text in this column some long text in this column}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this yields the error `Missing number, treated as zero. < to be read again > \relax l.786 \end{tabularx}.` I don't see what is different from the MWE in my application.

Comment: @bumblebee - Did you load the `calc` package? If not, you should replace `p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}` with `p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}`.

Comment: Excellent, this works! Amended the answer to clarify this beyond the MWE.